# BlackJack Java String[] not working

Tags: java, compilation, blackjack

SO I am having a bit of trouble here in a java game of BlackJack. I have switched from using hashmaps for the card names and values and converted it over to a String[] just because it is so much easier. However, I appeared to have broken some code in it:

```
private void createDeck(int numCards, int numSuits) {

    deck = new ArrayList<Card>();
    cardUsed = new ArrayList<Card>();
    if ((numCards % numSuits) > 0) return;

    for (int i=0; i < numSuits; i++) {
        for(int j=1; j <= (numCards / numSuits); j++) {
            deck.add(new Card(new Suit(i), j + "", j));
        }
    }
}
```

This won't run and gives me an unresolved compilation problem: The constructor Card(Suit, String, int) is undefined. However I have Card's parameters as Card(Suit, String[], int).   Is there a way to go around this by still using a String array? It underlines the `deck.add(new Card(new Suit(i), j + "", j));` in the program.

Here is the source for Card.java

```
public class Card  {

private String[] cardRank = new String[] {"Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", 
        "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King"} ;

private Suit suit = null;

private int cardValue = 0;

public Card(Suit suit, String[] cardRank, int cardValue) {
    this.cardRank = cardRank;
    this.suit = suit;
    this.cardValue = cardValue;
}

public String toString() {
    return cardRank + " of " + suit.getSuitName();
}

public String[] getCardRank() {
    return cardRank;
}

public void setCardRank(String[] cardRank) {
    this.cardRank = cardRank;
}

public Suit getSuit() {
    return suit;
}

public void setSuit(Suit suit) {
    this.suit = suit;
}

public int getCardValue() {
    return cardValue;
}

public void setCardValue(int cardValue) {
    this.cardValue = cardValue;
}
```

}

Comment: Can you post the source of Card.java?

Comment: Pass String array instead of String? Something like new String[]{j+""}?

Comment: `The constructor Card(Suit, String, int) is undefined` ... it means there no constructor in `Card` that takes a `Suit` and an `int` as arguments.

Comment: You know, it looks like what you really want is to have `cardRank` instead be a string, and to have a separate array of allowed ranks (which could probably be static).  You'd pass a string, rather than an array, to the constructor..and get one back from `getCardRank`.  (`setCardRank` probably shouldn't even exist, unless you actually need pure dumb beans for some reason.)

Comment: Alternatively, you could create Rank and Suit enums (which can stringify themselves), and pass those instead.

Comment: @cHao: Well, I have no idea how to use enum's or what they even are so I think I want to stick to using Strings and Arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
new Card(new Suit(i), new String[]{j + ""}, j)
```

You were passing as second parameter `j + ""`, which is a `String`. To pass a `String[]`, which is the expected type, just pack that string into a single-element array: `new String[]{j + ""}`.

On a more fundamental level: why is the card rank defined as a `String[]` in the first place? it should be a `String`, a single card only has one rank! better fix the `Card` class and change it to have a `private String cardRank` as attribute:

```
public class Card  {

    private Suit suit = null;
    private String cardRank;
    private int cardValue = 0;

    public Card(Suit suit, String cardRank, int cardValue) {
        this.cardRank = cardRank;
        this.suit = suit;
        this.cardValue = cardValue;
    }

}
```

Now the original initialization code will work as intended:

```
new Card(new Suit(i), j + "", j)
```

Comment: Wouldn't I place the cards and their values into a String[] though because then it can hold multiple cards and values without going through and defining each one individually?

Comment: @DarkZal: No...if you want to call the class `Card`, it should represent a single card.  If you want multiple cards, use an array -- or create a `Hand`, `Deck`, `CardPile`, or what-have-you.

Comment: You should declare an array of cards elsewhere (the BlackJack class perhaps?) but here you're defining only a _single_ card, and a single card has a single rank

Comment: Ahh okay, I get it now, so it would be better to just go ahead and change it back to a String. I have an `ArrayList<Card> hand` as my hand for the game.

Comment: That's right! . and that `ArrayList<Card> hand` should exist in a different class, the "parent" class of the game, which is the owner of all the cards

Comment: @Oscar: As the game goes the parent class is `Person` and the `Player` as well as the `Dealer` class extend `Person`. Then each `Player` is given a `Hand` of `Card`'s. Is this all correct? Just leaving out the deck and game engine classes.

Comment: @DarkZal it's a bit subjective, but see how it works out for you. If you find yourself that Person has mixed methods, some for manipulating the person's attributes (name, etc.) and others for the BlackJack game (start game, deal cards, etc.) then it might be a better idea to have a separate class for the game, and the Person class would have an attribute with that class

Comment: @ÓscarLópez: All of my classes are separate and only called to. My classes are as follows: `Suit`, `Card`, `Deck`, `Hand`, `Player`, `Dealer`, `Person`, and `GameEngine`. I'm to figure out and adjust to using all of the classes as Objects since Java is an OO language. Up until just last week I was programming Java functionally which was tough and broke code all the time. This definitely seems a lot easier although sometimes a few of the terms confuse me a little.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez: How should I go about giving the specific card a value however? I'm only getting null of spades as the output.

Comment: The code as shown will work, you're probably doing something else, somewhere else, and I can't figure that out without context. Time to post that new problem as a new, separate question

Comment: @ÓscarLópez the `private String cardRank;` returns as null. So that's where I'm thinking the problem is.

Comment: You're supposed to pass a card rank as the second parameter, not the number `j`. Use a value from that array you had at the beginning, passing the index: `new Card(new Suit(i), cardRanks[j-1], j)`

Comment: @ÓscarLópez: How do I get the `cardRanks` into the `Deck` class from `Card`? I used a setter a getter for the `String[] cardRanks` but it won't let me use that.

Comment: I can't possibly know, I have no idea how Deck is implemented. Please, _do_ post that as a different question, this discussion is too long already!

Answer (score 2):

Well I think this is bad design generally. But for this specific Question the answer would likely be to replace `j + ""` with `new String[] {j + ""}`

Comment: Why is it a bad design? I'm still in the process of learning the Java language so I don't know a whole lot yet.

Comment: Please post your Card class, then I can give some more analysis. But it's strange to convert the int-value into a string, integer-values are comparable much faster. Btw: You could tag my or the answer above as correct.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing in a `String`, not a `String[]`.  One is just a single object, while the other is an array of objects.

`j + ""` results in one `String`, not a set of `String`s.

You can solve this by placing the `String` into an array of `String`s before passing it into your constructor.